# Tab を押すとフォーカスが切り替わるのを禁止したい

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

最近、[テキストエディタ](https://github.com/vivisuke/openViVi)を開発しているのですが、ビューにフォーカスがあるとき、Tab キーを押すとフォーカスが別のウィジェットに移ってしまい、Tab文字を挿入することができません。
タブによるフォーカス移動を禁止する設定みたいなものがあったはずなのですが、それを思い出せません。
具体的にどうすればタブキーによるフォカース移動を禁止できるのか、ご教授いただけると助かります。

開発環境：Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, C++, Qt5.14

Answer (score 0):

ビューウィジェットで bool focusNextPrevChild(bool next); を再実装し、
false を返すとフォーカス移動が禁止され、keyPressEvent() がちゃんとコールされるようです。